# Call directive from ng-click of element inside a partial in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>


    <!--Core JS Libraries-->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!--Core UI Library-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Define an angular module for our app
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        //Define Routing for app
        myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
          function ($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/View1.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                }).
                when('/design', {
                    templateUrl: 'pages/2.html',
                    controller: 'DesignController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });
          }]);

        var controllers = {};
        controllers.HomeController = function ($scope) {
            $scope.GetView2 = function ($scope) {
                $('#one').hide();
                $('#two').show();

                myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        templateUrl: 'pages/view2.html'
                    }
                });
            };
        };
        controllers.DesignController = function ($scope) {

        };

        //adding the controllers to myApp angularjs app
        myApp.controller(controllers);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my View1.html:

```
<button ng-click="GetView2()">Get View 2</button>
<br />
<div class="row" id="one">
    <h1>View 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="row" id="two" style="display: none;">
    <h1>View 2</h1>
    <!--change the display to block and load partial here on above button click-->
    <my-directive></my-directive>

</div>
```

And View2.html:

```
<h3>Something in View2</h3>
```

Now,when I run the HTML, on Button click, View 1 heading chanegs to View 2 heading, so my routing and GetView2() function calls are working. But my `<my-directive>` is not getting updated with View2.html which I am calling in the directive in templateUrl.

I am new to AngularJS and trying to use ng-view and directives for multiple views type of scenario. I have read that I should avoid nested views, and implement directives, but I am not getting how to implement such a simple scenario.

I can easily replace content of Div with id="two" using jQuery, but I am trying to do it in proper angularjs way.

Comment: please, post directive `my-directive` code

Comment: @MaximShoustin my-directive code is also present in above code. I have posted the whole code actually.

Comment: @Pawan You're defining your directive inside a controller's scope method. That's plain wrong and it won't work.

Comment: @Stewie Yes I know its wrong.. but I am not able to find a correct answer on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve what you are trying.

First this

```
 $('#one').hide();
 $('#two').show();
```

should be avoided as this is direct DOM manipulation from Controller.

You should use or `ng-show` directive to show hide the element.

```
<div class="row" id="one" ng-show="currentView='one'">
<h1>View 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="row" id="two" ng-show="currentView='two'">
</div>
```

The controller should be

```
$scope.GetView2 = function ($scope) {
$scope.currentView='two';
}
```

For the directive that you have created can be done by `ng-include` such as

`<ng-include src='pages/view2.html' />`

and make sure there is a view at this path.

Comment: Two points: First: I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentView' of undefined" when I changed the "one" and "two" divs and added ng-show as you said. Error is on line: $scope.currentView = 'two'; in the controller. And second question: Where to add <ng-include...>

Comment: Ok, I moved the directive definition out of my Controller and then the directive is getting populated from the templateUrl html file. But this is happening during the load of my View1.html itself. I want this directive to get View2.html only on call of GetView2() function (which in turn is called on ng-click). Any ideas? So bacically, how can I load template inside a directive in a lazy load manner of due to some event.

Comment: Use `ng-if` instead of ng-show, and the DOM would get loaded when the condition is true.